# Trigger raises message when it's not supposed to

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, triggers

I have a trigger attached to a table that is supposed to raise exceptions when certain combinations of columns are not unique.

```
CREATE TRIGGER uniqueness BEFORE INSERT ON a
  BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'Record is not unique !')
    FROM a
    WHERE ((NEW.st <> 1) 
      AND (p = NEW.p)
      AND ((name = NEW.name) OR (safe_name = NEW.safe_name)));
  END;
```

but it seems to get triggered sometimes when it's not necessary.

For example if safe_name is `foo5`, and there is an existing record that has safe_name `foo-5`. But `foo5` != `foo-5` so why does that happen?

=============================================================

ok i found out why it happens. here's how you reproduce it in PHP:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
$pdo->sqliteCreateCollation('NS', 'strnatcasecmp');      

$pdo->query('CREATE TABLE a(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   st INTEGER NOT NULL,
   p  INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NS,
   safe_name NOT NULL COLLATE NS)');

$pdo->query('CREATE TRIGGER uniqueness BEFORE INSERT ON a
  BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "Record is not unique !")
    FROM a
    WHERE ((NEW.st <> 1) 
      AND (p = NEW.p)
      AND ((name = NEW.name) OR (safe_name = NEW.safe_name)));
  END;');

// success
$pdo->query('INSERT INTO a(st, p, name, safe_name) VALUES(2, 2, "Foo 5", "foo-5")');

// fail :(
$pdo->query('INSERT INTO a(st, p, name, safe_name) VALUES(2, 2, "foo  5", "foo5")');
```

Apparently the `Foo 5` name is equal `foo   5` when the collation thingy is active.

if I remove the `sqliteCreateCollation` call and the COLLATE NS statements it work :/

Is there any solution to this that allows me to keep my collation function? I only need it for ordering, but apparently it's used for comparisons too...

Comment: Can you post the table defs and some sample data that throws unexpectedly?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly name the columns like `a.safe_name = NEW.safe_name`

Comment: My guess would be that the criteria other than `safe_name` in the `SELECT` is matching.

Comment: I've added more details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to leave the collation in place, but switch it to binary for the trigger query only..

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
$pdo->sqliteCreateCollation('NS', 'strnatcasecmp');      

$pdo->query('CREATE TABLE a(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   st INTEGER NOT NULL,
   p  INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NS,
   safe_name NOT NULL COLLATE NS)');

$pdo->query('CREATE TRIGGER uniqueness BEFORE INSERT ON a
  BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "Record is not unique !")
    FROM a
    WHERE ((NEW.st <> 1) 
      AND (p = NEW.p)
      AND ((name COLLATE BINARY = NEW.name) OR (safe_name COLLATE BINARY = NEW.safe_name)));
  END;');

// success
$pdo->query('INSERT INTO a(st, p, name, safe_name) VALUES(2, 2, "Foo 5", "foo-5")');

// should work now
$pdo->query('INSERT INTO a(st, p, name, safe_name) VALUES(2, 2, "foo  5", "foo5")');
```

Comment: is `COLLATE BINARY` the default collation?

Comment: thanks! I removed the COLLATE statement from create table and I added COLLATE NS to the ORDER BY statement in the queries where I want to use natural sort. seems to work

Answer (score 1):

You have specifically set your collation to do a case-insensitive comparison.  Try changing it to:

```
$pdo->sqliteCreateCollation('NS', 'strnatcmp');
```

And see if that helps.

Comment: I can't do that because I need case insensitive comparisons for ordering results. But I don't know why does sqlite use it for selects where x=y. It makes no sense...